# RetroPie + 4.0" TFT screen not working

Tags: screen

I have tried everything except reinstalling RetroPie, because I want to try every last thing, before I spend hours reinstalling all my games and so on. Here it goes:

I bought a screen from AliExpress: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Pi/32378324026.html - I immediately plugged it in, and now the screen lights up (but it's white).

I followed all the guides I could find, but generally all I had to do was:

```
Under Advanced Options:
Overscan: disable.
Device Tree: enable.
SPI: enable and load kernel module by default.
Audio: force 3.5mm headphone jack (since HDMI will be disconnected later).
```

After doing all this, it said:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'spi_bcm2708': No such device

So I read a ton of sites saying I could blacklist 2708 and use 2835 instead, but after trying all the possible things inside `/boot/cmdline.txt` and all kind of files, but after rebooting literally 30 times, I still haven't gotten the screen to turn on with something.

What can I do? I followed a bunch of guides:

https://learn.adafruit.com/running-opengl-based-games-and-emulators-on-adafruit-pitft-displays/retropie-setup
http://www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/
http://diyhacking.com/raspberry-pi-touchscreen-lcd-tutorial/

And so on. Nothing works. What can I do? How can I check if SPI is enabled and I can actually use the screen? I'm really stuck and I would love some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: [RPi 2 and 3.95 TFT ili9488](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44179/rpi-2-and-3-95-tft-ili9488/44472#44472)

Thanks to @alezbarra I finally got my issue fixed. It took a few hours and about 15 installations of various distibutions, but I finally got it working.

Now to make it work on RetroPie as well...

Comment: Would you please write an answer describing what you needed to do to get RetroPi working with your system?

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.