# OLED 128x128 is not displaying correctly the colors

Tags: python, display

I'm having trouble using the OLED SSD1351. I'm running python programs with the luma.oled library.
When I run a program that uses colors, these are displayed incorrectly, red is displayed like blue, blue like red, yellow like blue (too?), and so on.

I run my program examples in the physical OLED and in the pygame emulator from luma for reference.

This is what is being displayed:

[image] [image]

And this are the programs run in pygame (this is how it should be like):

[image] [image]

Does this have a solution or this is a hardware problem?? (I mean, the OLED)

This is the [link](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/4000380926640.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.274263c0H0qxdm) to the OLED I bought.

Comment: without seeing your code, the answer is a pineapple - yellow (red+green) looks more like cyan (blue+green) - so it looks like a r/b colour swap - almost like it's an endian problem ... RGB vs BGR

Comment: @JaromandaX I forgot to mention that the display was bought on AliExpress, should I add the link to the one I bought?

Comment: @JaromandaX I didn't add code because I don't see a problem in the code, as you say that is a problem with color swap, is there a way I can fix that?

Comment: Nothing to do with the Pi.

Comment: yeah sure, link it - and the code, where did you get the code

Comment: @JaromandaX I added the link to the product at the end of the post, and I got the code from the [luma.examples](https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.examples) repository on github.

Comment: I modified a little another part of the first program to switch red and blue, and it looks like it should look like. The thing is that I don't know how I can do this with programs that uses images (because I can't switch the colors).

Comment: It's a different display type, but I'm pretty sure it boils down to the same issue as this Q/A https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58322/ili9488-display-color-problem/95288#95288

Answer (score 0):

I would not think that you have a hardware problem as you do have text and color
on your display. I bought a display just like your, except it has a cable already
attached and two pin are labeled differently, DIN for SDA (MOSI) and CLK for SCL(SCLK).
I spend a month or two looking on the web for an easy setup, but found
none. Adafruit and luma seem to be the answer, but too many libraries and very
complicated.

I did piece together bits of information that I will share that is pretty simple
and all is available on Pi 4B running Raspbian 10.11 buster 5.10.63-v7l+.

At the end of /boot/config.txt, add these two lines:

```
dtoverlay=spi0-1cs,no_miso
dtoverlay=ssd1351-spi,dc_pin=9,reset_pin=7
```

Note: I am using SPI0, with 1 chip select, with no MISO. Loading the ssd1351-spi
module with DC and RESET pins. I use the MISO(pin 9) and CS1(pin 7) for DC and
RESET. ADJUST TO YOUR PLAN WIRING. After reboot, check with commands:

```
sudo vcdbg log msg 2>&1 | grep -E 'overlay|dtparam'
ls /dev/fb*
fbset -fb /dev/fb1 (or fbset -i -fb /dev/fb1)
```

Should have Loaded overlay 'spi0-1cs', dtparam: no_miso=true, Loaded overlay 'ss
d1351-spi', dtparam: dc_pin=9, dtparam: reset_pin=7, or error message.
Device /dev/fb0 is the HDMI device and /dev/fb1 is the ssd1351 device.
The last command shows mode, geometry, ..., ..., rgba.
Power off, wire your device, power on and everything is set up. All that is needed
is to write to frame buffer 1.

A simple Python pygame program will work just fine.

```
#!/usr/env python3

# Program to test spi0 using python on display ssd1351
#   /boot/config.txt
#      dtoverlay=spi0-1cs,param=no_miso
#      dtoverlay=ssd1351-spi,dc_pin=9,reset_pin=7
#   Check after reboot
#      sudo vcdbg log msg 2>&1 | grep -E 'overlay|dtparam'
#      fbset -fb /dev/fb1 
# Wiring for SPI0 with power off
#   physical pin 17(3.3v) -> VCC,  20(gnd) -> GND
#   GPIO10(MOSI) -> DIN, GPIO11(SCLK) -> CLK, GPIO8(CE0) -> CS
#   GPIO9 -> D/C, GPIO7 -> Reset 
#   

import pygame
import subprocess as sp

geom = sp.getoutput("fbset -fb /dev/fb1 | grep geometry").split()
xres, yres, bpp = int(geom[1]), int(geom[2]), int(geom[5])

pygame.init()
oled = pygame.Surface((xres, yres))    # Set surface to display
a, b = (110), 255                # font color selection
black = pygame.Color("black")    # black font color
white = pygame.Color("white")    # white font color
pygame.font.init()
defaultFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None,24)

def refresh():    # refresh or update oled display frame buffer
    fd = open("/dev/fb1","wb")    # open, write binary
    fd.write(oled.convert(bpp,0).get_buffer())    # convert to
    fd.close()    # close file                    # 16 bit write
    pygame.time.wait(2000)    # time wait 2 seconds

def oled_display(cname, colr=(0)):    # color name, color
    if colr == (0):                   # If color not supplied
        colr = pygame.Color(cname)    # get color from dict

    oled.fill(colr)    # fill display with selected color
    fntcolr = black
    if all(a > x for x in colr[:-1]) or b > sum(list(colr[:-1])):
        fntcolr = white    # select font color
    
    # The next 2 cmds renders the bg color name and color numbers
    # to the surface with font color at pos 2, 0 and 2, 28.
    oled.blit(defaultFont.render(cname, False, fntcolr),(2, 0))
    oled.blit(defaultFont.render(str(colr[:-1]), False, fntcolr), (2, 28))
    refresh()    # copy surface buffer to oled frame buffer

for cname in "red", "green", "blue", "firebrick4", "green4", "blue4":
    oled_display(cname)    # short demo with black and white font
    
oled.fill(black)    # Turn display off.
refresh()

exit()    # Commit out for all colors in dictionary.

for cname, colr in pygame.colordict.THECOLORS.items():
    if cname[:4] != "grey":    # grey and gray are the same color
        oled_display(cname, colr)

oled.fill(black)
refresh()
```