# RPi 2 and 3.95 TFT

Tags: gpio, pi-2

I have tried as per [RPi 2 and 3.95 TFT ili9488](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44179/rpi-2-and-3-95-tft-ili9488) comment, But it is not working with my Raspberry Pi (Ubuntu Mate OS). What can i do to work my display with RPi 2 and 3.95 TFT with ubuntu Mate os??? Please help !!!

Comment: I mean when i am tringas below :, the screen gets blank (White). Nothing is going to be display on the screen. I have mentioned link in my description that i have tried.

Comment: please put the information about the white screen into the question (use the edit button) ... also add the wiring diagram

Comment: Well, since other people have tried that tutorial and it worked for them, you obviously did something differently. Unless you explain exactly what you did, nobody will be able to help you.